# How to hide cell if value 0

Tags: google-sheets

I am making a spreadsheet that shows values based on another sheet, where it's supposed to only show values greater than 0. Whenever a cell is 0, it needs to hide the cell itself and the cell on its left. in this case, the value 0 is based on a simple equation: `=B4-Blad1!C4`.

Comment: You cannot hide a cell, either you have to hide a row or column or apply some kind of conditional formatting.

Comment: Should it be an empty cell?

Comment: @HarshaVardhan hiding the row would be an acceptable solution

Comment: @Gogowitsch it should be hidden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fully hide the row, you can use the filter function:

1. Draw a selection rectangle on the data in which rows should disappear
2. Click on the Funnel icon to start the filter function
   [image]
3. In the column header, click on the new icon, 3 horizontal green lines in a triangle shape.
4. Make sure checkboxes remain before the non-zero values

For animations, follow the example here:
https://yagisanatode.com/2018/05/26/how-to-hide-a-row-based-on-a-cell-value-in-google-sheets-with-filter-or-google-apps-script/